# iterable.iterator().hasNext() returning false after mocking behaviour

Tags: java, mockito

I have mocked an iterable and added when conditions for `iterable.iterator()` and `iterable.iterator().next()` and `iterable.iterator().hasNext()`.

I can print and see that `iterable.iterator()` when called gives me an iterator but `hasNext()` seems to be returning false even after mocking it.

Here is how I have mocked the `Iterator` and `Iterable`

```
// mock iterator
final Iterator mockIterator = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
final Iterable mockIterable = Mockito.mock(Iterable.class);
Mockito.when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
Mockito.when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockGoogleAdsRow);
Mockito.when(mockIterable.iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
Mockito.when(searchPagedResponse.iterateAll()).thenReturn(mockIterable);
```

I have this for loop in code which needs to be tested (verified)

```
// System.out.println("response.iterateAll()" + response.iterateAll());
// This prints --> response.iterateAll()Mock for Iterable, hashCode: 1027306253
// System.out.println("next " + response.iterateAll().iterator().next());
// This prints --> next Mock for GoogleAdsRow, hashCode: -767510433

-------------> HERE THIS PART IS FAILING, HASNEXT 
// System.out.println("has next " + response.iterateAll().iterator().hasNext());
// This prints --> has next false
// System.out.println("size " + Iterators.size(response.iterateAll().iterator()));
// This prints size 0
for (final GoogleAdsRow googleAdsRow : response.iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println("Inside loop");
```

Any Help is appreciated

EDIT :
`searchPagedResponse` is mocked like this

```
searchPagedResponse = Mockito.mock(GoogleAdsServiceClient.SearchPagedResponse.class);
mockGoogleAdsRow = Mockito.mock(GoogleAdsRow.class);
Mockito.when(mockGoogleAdsServiceClient.searchPagedCallable()).thenReturn(callable);
Mockito.when(mockGoogleAdsServiceClient.searchPagedCallable().call(searchGoogleAdsRequest)).thenReturn(searchPagedResponse);
```

Comment: How is the `searchPagedResponse` mocked?

Comment: Are `response` and `searchPagedResponse` the same objects?

Comment: Yes `response` and `searchPagedResponse` are the same objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured easy way to do it was simply doing this, instead of mocking an iterator.

```
Mockito.when(searchPagedResponse.iterateAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(mockGoogleAdsRow));
```

Not sure why mocking the iterator was failing,
but I have recently started working with Java, so simple things, I have been doing in round about ways.